# Use active club solution in Squarespace

Tags: squarespace

I am new to squarespace and active club solution. I want to give custom styling to one of my elements inside the iframe provided by the active club solutions.

Can anyone please tell me, how can i implement the custom styling inside the elements inside the iframe in squarespace?

Answer (score 0):

It appears, from the following link, that this is possible by obtaining a template file from Active Club Solutions, writing one's own CSS within it, adding the file to one's Squarespace website [via file upload](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205813928-Uploading-and-managing-files), then providing the URL to that CSS file to Active Club Solutions: https://www.secureclub.net/Help/cart/cart_css.html#override

> To modify the iframes’ format and appearance, you will need to install
>   and edit an “override” style sheet. Active Club support will provide a
>   template for this file, named CompanyNameiframe.css, which you may
>   place in any desired location. You must provide Active Club Solutions
>   with the link to this file; it must be on an SSL-secured server,
>   accessible through an `https://` link.

Comment: Should i need to contact Active Club Solutions to obtain a css file?

Comment: It sounds that way from how I read it. It seems to me you'll then need to edit the CSS yourself accordingly, the provide them the URL.

Comment: oh, Ok. Can i style css elements insidr iframe?

Comment: That's exactly it. You get the CSS file from them, you edit it in order to style the elements within the iframe, then you upload it to your Squarespace site, then provide them the link/URL. At that point, whenever their system generates the internal markup of the iframe, it will load along with it your CSS file, styling the elements with the iframe.

Comment: Hi @Brandon, Can you please make a look at below link. My forgot password is also not working.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53809620/password-reset-not-working-in-active-club-solutions-in-squarespace-website

Comment: Hi @Brandon, I obtain the css file from active club solutions. But didn't found any class which is implemented on iframes in css file. Now, Can i directly style iframes?